# (Golang) How to restrict ammount of command line output

Tags: go, command-line

During executing something golang application, display of command line is overflowed by error messages 
when something panic occured.
Provided there were lots of goroutine running, it could'be appeared.

However, information I want to know is just a few lines from top of output.
How can I restrict that feature I desire?

Thank you.

Harry

Comment: From the outside only, e.g. via `head`.

Comment: see: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/KubsC2vYcXg/discussion

Comment: Yes, I posted that message on google group. And I got good solution.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind. You can pick what works for you.

1. Panicparse

Marc-Antoine Ruel -- fantastic developer -- created [panicparse](https://github.com/maruel/panicparse). Run your program, assign *stderr* to *stdout*, pipe that into panicparse, and you're good to go.

```
go run example.go 2>&1 | pp
```

Panicparse will deduplicate and dedensify the output >50% while also making it far more readable.

Check out the screenshots in the README.

2. *Head*

If the information you're looking for is always at the top of the stacktrace, then maybe it's just a simple case of piping the output to *head*.

We want to run our program; allowing it to output to *stdout*/terminal like normal, but we want to limit the amount of information the panic displays with *head*. Remember, panics are written to *stderr*. So piping *stderr* to a process substitution should work on most systems:

```
go run example.go 2> >(head)
```

Comment: I got it, it'd be helpful for me!! I try it! Thanks a lot!